Path analysis with perfect fit
I'm trying to determine if I can display two regression models and the covariance between the dependent variables in one unified model using path analysis with lavaan in R. In the following (scaled) model, birds are observed in a two-hour interval. "percent_flying" represents the time birds spent flying, "sounds_per_minute" represents the average number of sounds per minute, "social_metrics" is a score indicating the number of birds in close surroundings, and "gender" represents the gender of the bird.
I want to examine the effects of social metrics and gender on the percent of time spent flying and sounds per minute, as well as the relationship between the two dependent variables.
According to fitMeasures(fit), the model fit is perfect. However, I do not have any latent variables in this model. Is this approach valid, even with a perfect fit, or am I presenting the data with a flawed statistical model? See below.
library(lavaan)

df <- data.frame(
  percent_fly = c(-0.009132161, 1.355084750, -0.789623287, 0.153558503, -0.045353187, 1.335985988, -0.889525395, -0.015340332, 0.331474633, -2.542857423, 0.250094033, 0.381178491, 0.072157028, -1.056986872, 1.226990803, 0.736182506, 0.091479099, -0.248885459, -0.429463409, -0.186420266, 1.283842582, 0.406202671, 0.124812145, 0.811079594, 0.733203004, 0.737158995, 0.024809386, 0.017476792, 0.478135183, 0.875088003, -0.377248732, -0.321579552, 0.584544613, 0.049095912, 0.094411047, 1.155091638, 1.784065854, 1.195165958, 2.236810669, -1.211473115, -0.050372916, -0.610139661, -0.072998666, 0.255992828, -1.501354403, -0.703623905, -0.349937208, -0.814189605, 0.294325152, 1.823947177, 0.533066501, -0.327349984, -2.677155432, -0.416048767, -1.360454064, -1.529342487, -0.635114063, 1.295904758, -0.442936632, -0.585189970, -0.276132589, -0.528200754, -0.879854756, -0.033692382, -0.796823752, -0.516714106, -1.603625580, 0.720721844, -0.636660641, -1.475570770, -1.424693429, 0.020145034, -1.520720663, -0.203343263, -1.011689335, -0.037578611, 0.798928492, -0.418578264, 0.072407586, 0.526641207, 1.612379665, 0.029766904, 0.615861352, 0.095577526, 0.305220122, 0.013403639, 0.310529646, -0.486932647, 1.937346406, -0.626331653, -0.269506879, -0.543391226, 0.489787823, 3.054104022, 2.465062330, -0.403912755, -2.098407495, 0.247301163, 0.951123634, -0.830787098),
  sounds_per_minute = c(0.5750445924, -1.2314829562, 2.5848529973, -0.2395739056, 0.2708677682, -0.5004788560, -0.2563165092, 0.4112438140, 0.4466410453, 0.6288690152, -0.0632953630, 0.3558378591, -0.1930618193, -0.6267370149, -1.3589613058, -0.6766351382, 0.7463284878, 1.0385684827, -0.2113423175, 0.2081651801, -0.6888713028, -0.9110453414, 0.4842059225, -0.8084813386, -0.0928563585, -0.3645253498, -0.0528844888, -0.4731596697, -0.3877606046, 0.9219070337, 2.2897304910, 0.4552303285, -0.9900264335, 0.6867510160, -0.2028912932, -1.0719411067, -2.5183599566, -1.4173777742, -1.5879204612, 0.3139686429, 0.5520707204, 0.4225084950, 0.1280381561, 1.8665071690, 1.0503629496, 1.1158672016, -0.0223836355, -1.2900135748, 0.7931033864, -0.3600399547, -0.8408100330, 0.4520321930, 1.0114195601, -0.2306811153, 1.4233726761, 2.3047665402, 0.7756649963, -0.8187269285, 0.5770723828, -0.3610546463, 0.0849039410, 0.7400349797, 1.0938429324, 0.3777396129, 0.2627950583, 0.7183245950, -0.4396127961, -1.0528016833, 0.2396633959, 1.1165161287, 1.9686777758, 0.4580465591, 2.3316685449, 0.2745342295, -0.5965867375, 0.2181984217, -1.1530739476, 0.6382775645, -0.8884837416, -0.9030449277, -1.4811909382, 0.0864574749, 0.9209790437, -0.5158495526, -0.6701566818, 0.8063174329, -0.8841196358, 0.4453183594, -1.4424814456, -0.9366713083, -0.2204066280, -0.7458098250, -1.5974950987, -2.1843401190, -1.8464905789, 0.0160172792, 1.7068005736, 0.0006538824, -1.1835906911, 0.2038301344),
  social_metrics = c(-0.69918953, -1.52984878, 1.28800709, -1.59616764, 0.95905975, -1.75093469, 0.35790436, 1.29777825, 0.99458632, 1.49921242, 0.20590606, -1.05318444, -0.74246675, -0.64514614, -1.66456795, -0.75204014, -0.02994398, 0.22032846, -1.62769568, 0.92965453, -0.43699530, -0.20731357, 0.56300458, -1.11185157, 0.66119509, 1.07761753, 0.30106441, 0.69247523, -0.89994787, 0.38246809, 1.47595554, -0.59546355, -1.38516451, 1.12700595, -0.46611824, -0.36219143, -1.09649718, -1.10701326, 0.20537096, -0.24253573, 0.21798897, 0.15899737, 0.48556800, 1.08954729, 0.13084782, 0.49331612, 0.73281475, -1.31959222, 1.08511180, -1.39769034, 0.25191334, 0.50381389, 0.50863954, 1.05923539, 1.32995167, 0.15729028, 1.13422278, -0.86938247, 0.16937808, 1.22194391, 0.70297769, 1.33528306, 0.20039147, 0.16871374, 0.85759561, 0.42715729, 1.18445568, -1.04865050, 0.82993301, 1.46095107, 0.73608502, 0.91644098, 1.24849911, 1.31196152, 0.73361241, -0.72261273, -1.48770849, 0.56538446, -1.11621984, -0.06819641, -1.67022997, -0.35310735, -0.07577571, 0.50349339, -1.15519043, 1.12584763, -0.63397466, -0.50222723, 0.59434865, -1.09376133, 0.13374376, 0.39216386, -2.43317902, -3.13871204, -1.43344846, 0.30645663, 0.70875541, -0.24696393, -1.18734878, 0.51812247),
  gender = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
  )

model <- '
  # Regression paths
  percent_fly ~ social_metrics + gender
  sounds_per_minute ~ social_metrics + gender

  # Covariance between the outcomes
  percent_fly ~~ sounds_per_minute
'
fit <- sem(model, data = df)
summary(fit)
fitMeasures(fit)


Your model has perfect fit because it's saturated, i.e., you have 0 degrees of freedom, so there is no possibility for fit indices calculations. I believe lavaan sem estimates the variances of and covariance between social metric and gender by default, so with 4 paths, residual variances of DVs and covariance between them you have 10 things to estimate. If you want model fit indices, consider constraining some parameters in your model.

But to my understanding, your path coefficients and their SEs are fine, if you just want them.

I want to create two regression models (percent_fly ~ social_metrics + gender, and sounds_per_minute ~ social_metrics + gender) and examine the correlation between percent_fly and sounds_per_minute. I could create two separate linear regression models and another model to examine the correlation between percent_fly and sounds_per_minute (e.g., Pearson's correlation). However, that approach involves three separate models using the same data. I wonder if the unified path analysis in my post above is a better approach in a peer-reviewed article. I only need the coefficients and SE, yes.

I'm not the best with SEM, I hope you get an answer from someone with more expertise, but IMO your path model is a good choice in this situation because it gives you the correlation between dependents, even though you can't get model fit.
